# I have install magento latest 2.2.3 on local but on adding custom css file it does not refelect in the source code

Tags: magento2.2.3

I have added code in the default XML block(FOR CUSTOM CSS FILE) in my custom theme and after this made `content-deploy` also but it was still not reflecting in my source code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/theme.css"/>
        <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: IF U change the css ,You have  to run the below commands  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: already tried but still not showing...

Comment: can you share the default layout file for adding the css..?

Comment: make sure that your css files are located in <current theme root>/web/css path

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to call custom files in your custom theme:

> Step1: Add theme.css and bootstrap.min.css in "current theme root directory/web/css"

Custom files are stored in root path because you have given path like:

```
 <css src="css/theme.css"/>
 <css src="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

> Step2:after complete first step fire bolow 2  commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Refresh page and check your changes.
Hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: I have place exactly in the same format but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry to say but still facing same problem...

Comment: It might be some little mistake to configure theme.

Comment: on deplying the same css files are generated in the pub/static folder but don't know why it doesn't reflect in the souce code...